# Sorting Pandas dataframe based on a list value on a per row basis

Tags: pandas

This dataframe has the columns `["Monthly","Weekly","Daily"]` and each row is comprised of lists or `None` type.

How do I align the list entries with the correct columns?

For example on row 1 the lists containing the daily and monthly strings should be swapped with each other.  On row 0 the list should be moved to the `Daily` column.  Weekly is correct for both rows.

[image]

**Data**

`{'Monthly': {0: [1.352129999999999, '20', 'daily'], 1: [1.344164999999999, '12', 'daily']}, 'Weekly': {0: [1.35305, '12', 'weekly'], 1: [1.34481, '11', 'weekly']}, 'Daily': {0: None, 1: [1.3449900000000001, '4', 'monthly']}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recreate your data

```
dat = {i: {f: [*_, f] for *_, f in filter(None, lists)} for i, *lists in df.itertuples()}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dat, 'index').mask(pd.isna, None)

                            daily                 weekly                           monthly
0  [1.352129999999999, 20, daily]  [1.35305, 12, weekly]                              None
1  [1.344164999999999, 12, daily]  [1.34481, 11, weekly]  [1.3449900000000001, 4, monthly]
```

---

Just noticed that column names weren't capitalized.

```
dat = {i: {f.title(): [*_, f] for *_, f in filter(None, lists)} for i, *lists in df.itertuples()}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dat, 'index').mask(pd.isna, None)

                            Daily                 Weekly                           Monthly
0  [1.352129999999999, 20, daily]  [1.35305, 12, weekly]                              None
1  [1.344164999999999, 12, daily]  [1.34481, 11, weekly]  [1.3449900000000001, 4, monthly]
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the last item in the list recreate the data frame

```
#df = pd.DataFrame(d)
out = df.applymap(lambda x: {x[-1]: x} if x is not None else None).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).apply(pd.Series).groupby(level=0).first()
Out[276]: 
                            daily  ...                           monthly
0  [1.352129999999999, 20, daily]  ...                               NaN
1  [1.344164999999999, 12, daily]  ...  [1.3449900000000001, 4, monthly]
[2 rows x 3 columns]
```